# How do you determine the maximum long value in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

How would you find the maximum `long` value supported on your system within an application in Objective-C?  That is, how do we determine what the largest value is that `long` can represent?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As in C: include limits.h, and look at LONG_MAX or INT_MAX.

Comment: This was it. But for objective-c, no needed to add the include file. This SO question answered it all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107544/types-in-objective-c-on-iphone

Answer (score -10):

```
public class Main 
{
    public void displayMinAndMaxValuesOfLong() 
    {

        System.out.println(Long.MIN_VALUE);
        System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Main().displayMinAndMaxValuesOfLong();
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 not only is this the wrong language but I had to correct the formatting of the code.

Comment: It's also just plain weird code. Why would you instantiate Main in main() and call an instance method for this?