# Max value for a UIView's tag property

Tags: uiview

This is really just curiosity, but is there a max value for the tag property?  I'd assume that the tag is an UINT, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800015/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-nsinteger

Comment: Not duplicate, but related. Could have just looked at the documentation for `UIView` and noted that the `tag` is an `NSInteger` though. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "tag" property is an NSInteger. From Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSInteger):

> NSInteger Used to describe an integer.
>
> typedef long NSInteger; Discussion When building 32-bit applications,
>   NSInteger is a 32-bit integer. A 64-bit application treats NSInteger
>   as a 64-bit integer.

And the max size is `NSIntegerMax`. Go, print it to the console.