# Comparison of constant 10000000000 with expression of type 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') is always false

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to get billion and million values from Abacus game , on iphone 5s and on iphone 6 its give me values correctly ,but on iphone 4s and on iphone 5 its give me values in minus format , i was try out with data type long long , long but still not give me correct value here is my code which works fine on iphone 5s and 6 but give warning and give number in minus format ,can anyone help me in this please 
here is image of my code

```
NSString *digitLabelText;
if([self digit] == 0)
{
    digitLabelText= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[self digit]];
}
else
{
    if([self placeValue] == ONE || [self placeValue] == TEN ||
       [self placeValue] == ONE_HUNDRED || [self placeValue] == ONE_THOUSAND)
    {
        digitLabelText= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[self digit]];
    }
    else if([self placeValue] == TEN_THOUSAND)
    {
        digitLabelText= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld,000",(long)[self digit]/ONE_THOUSAND];
    }
    else if([self placeValue] == HUNDRED_THOUSAND)
    {
        digitLabelText= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld,000", (long)[self digit]/ONE_THOUSAND];
    }
    else if([self placeValue] == ONE_MILLION)
    {
        digitLabelText= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld mil", (long)[self digit]/ONE_MILLION];
    }
    else if([self placeValue] == TEN_MILLION)
    {
        digitLabelText= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld mil", (long)[self digit]/ONE_MILLION];
    }
    else if([self placeValue] == HUNDRED_MILLION)
    {
        digitLabelText= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld mil", (long)[self digit]/ONE_MILLION];
    }
    else if([self placeValue] == ONE_BILLION)
    {
        //issue come from this in iphone 4s ,5 digitLabelText= [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%ld bil", (long)[self digit]/ONE_BILLION];
    }
    else if([self placeValue] == TEN_BILLION)
    {
        digitLabelText= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld bil", (long)[self digit]/ONE_BILLION];///ONE_BILLION];
    }
    else if([self placeValue] == HUNDRED_BILLION)
    {
        digitLabelText= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld bil", (long)[self digit]/ONE_BILLION];///ONE_BILLION];
    }
    else if([self placeValue] == ONE_TRILLION)
    {
        digitLabelText= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld tril", (long)[self digit]/ONE_TRILLION];///ONE_TRILLION];
    }
}
digitLabel.text = digitLabelText;
```

see my code please
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U24oA.png

Comment: Please include your code in the comments.  External links can break.

Comment: Look up "`NSInteger` max value" to see why.

Comment: Also, this seems like something of an XY problem. The _actual_ solution to your problem seems to be logarithms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum value of NSInteger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800015/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-nsinteger)

Answer (score 3):

The size of NSInteger is platform dependent.

iPhone 5s and superior are 64 bit so the maximum value you can have is `2^63 - 1` (roughly 9,22 * 10^18).

iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 are 32 bit so the maximum value you can have is `2^31 - 1` = `2 147 483 647` which is always smaller than `10 000 000 000`.

You can use `int64_t` instead of NSInteger to have 64 bit integer on all platform and solve your problem.

Comment: @Asmita Did you try to change the type of `placeValue` to `int64_t` and recompile ? Do you still have the same warning ?

Comment: warning goes now thanks but giving number in minus like on 500000000 giving me -167890874 like this number

Comment: @Asmita Then you should still have other portion of codes that uses `NSInteger` instead of ìnt64_t`. You have to replace them as well.

Comment: i replace it to int64_t  other place also still not working @Raphael

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider for a moment how an abacus works, and how you can leverage that:

## What is an abacus?

An abacus is a calculation tool that works as follows: It has a series of rods, each with a series of beads, each rod having a value equal to *its number of beads multiplied by ten to the power of the position of the rod*, or *b * 10<sup>p</sup>*, or `bEp`.

## How can this be used to your advantage?

Instead of storing the huge numbers you currently are, consider storing the value of each rod of your abacus as something along the lines of `typedef struct : uint8_t { uint8_t value : 4, exponent : 4; } rod_value_t;`.

A `rod_value_t` can in this case store a number up to `1E16`, which is on the order of the range of a 64 bit integer.

Now, each rod only stores a single digit, so you'll need one of these for each rod, but since you are using the exponents and digits directly, and (apprently) storing each rod in either case, this is pretty massive space saving all the same.

If you want to store larger numbers than `1E16`, you could divide the struct up a little differently, such as for instance `typedef struct : uint16_t { uint16_t value : 4, exponent : 12; } rod_value_t;`, which will allow you to store, with the appropriate number of rods, basically any number you can conceive of (and quite a few you can't).

Comment: yes you right , i used one third party using that done all beads, columns, beadbehaviour all works fine on iphone 6 and 5s but giving error on iphone 4s  and on 5 as per  Raphaël say used int64_t its also not work? can you help me in this , it will great for me @Williham Totland

Comment: @Asmita Step away from large integer sizes alltogether and store the exponent and vauee for each column instead.

Comment: sorry not getting you @Williham Totland

Comment: @asmita Instead of storing, like you do, 10000000 for the number place and 5 for the column value, store 7 for the exponent and 5 for the value.

Comment: sorry still not understood i am too irritated beacuse this game , if you have time can you take look on my demo game please its help me lot @Williham Totland

Comment: @asmita I'm sorry, I just don't know how to make it clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121288/discussion-between-asmita-and-williham-totland).