# NSNumber limit?

Tags: objective-c, ios

What is the highest int that NSNumber allows? I've seen the answer elsewhere on these forums hence why I'm deeply confused here.

```
int miles = 35000;
vehicle.mileage = [NSNumber numberWithInt:miles];
NSLog(@"int value = %d", miles);
NSLog(@"mileage = %@", vehicle.mileage);
```

The output is:

```
int value = 35000
mileage = -30536
```

I must be missing some terrible easy here, but can someone explain to me why this is not working correctly?

**UPDATE:**
After looking further, vehicle.mileage is getting set correctly to 35000 but when I display this via NSLog(@"%@", vehicle.mileage) it is outputting it incorrectly. I have yet to find the "magic" value when this stops working because as of now, it works for values up to ~30,000.

Comment: If you replace `vehicle.mileage = [NSNumber numberWithInt:miles]` with `NSNumber *mileage = [NSNumber numberWithInt:miles]` and then change `NSLog(@"mileage = %@", vehicle.mileage);` to `NSLog(@"mileage = %@", mileage);` you will get the expected result: `mileage = 35000`, so I expect the problem is with the `mileage` property in `vehicle`. Check that its setter isn't doing something funky. Is it definitely of `NSNumber` type?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely NSNumber type - @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * mileage;

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853733/what-nsnumber-integer-16-32-64-in-core-data-should-i-use-to-keep-nsuinteger) provided the answer. Simple mistake but good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSNumber is just a wrapper so it goes in overflow when the wrapped primitive type goes in overflow.
So if you use *numberWithInt* the maximum number allowed is INT_MAX (defined in limits.h), if you use a *numberWithFloat* the maximum number allowed is FLOAT_MAX, and so on.
So in this case you aren't going in overflow, I doubt that INT_MAX would be so low.

Answer (score 1):

> **Overview**
>
> NSNumber is a subclass of NSValue that offers a value as any C scalar
>   (numeric) type. It defines a set of methods specifically for setting
>   and accessing the value as a signed or unsigned char, short int, int,
>   long int, long long int, float, or double or as a BOOL. (Note that
>   number objects do not necessarily preserve the type they are created
>   with.) It also defines a compare: method to determine the ordering of
>   two NSNumber objects.

So `NSNumber` is as big as what it wraps. For your unexpected result you can check comment bellow your qestion from @sjs.

Answer (score 0):

`+numberWithInt:` interprets the value as signed int. Mileage would never be negative, so I suggest using `[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:]`

Answer (score 0):

The limit `NSNumber` integer can have is known as `INT_MAX`but 35, 000 is nowhere close to that. The problem must be with `vehicle` object or the `mileage` property in the `vehicle`, either of them may be `nil`

So, go ahead and log with this conditional statement:

```
if (!vehicle) {
 NSLog(@"Vehicle is nil");
}
else if (!vehicle.mileage) {
 NSLog(@"Vehicle's mileage is nil");
}
```

Tell me your result