# List of Scalar Data Types

Tags: objective-c, types, scalar

Im looking for a list of all the scalar data types in Objective C, complete with their ranges (max/min values etc).

Sorry for the simple question, Im just really struggling to find anything like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `int`              An integer value between +/– 2,147,483,647.
- `unsigned int`     An integer value between 0 and 4,294,967,296.
- `float`            A floating point value between +/– 16,777,216.
- `double`           A floating point value between +/– 2,147,483,647.
- `long`             An integer value varying in size from 32 bit to 64 bit depending on architecture.
- `long long`        A 64-bit integer.
- `char`             A single character. Technically it’s represented as an `int`.
- `BOOL`             A boolean value, can be either YES or NO.
- `NSInteger`        When compiling for 32-bit architecture, same as an `int`, when compiling for 64-bit architecture,+/– 4,294,967,296.
- `NSUInteger`       When compiling for 32-bit architecture, same as an `unsigned int`, when compiling for 64-bit architecture, value between 0 and 2^64

[Source](http://www.scribd.com/doc/80232926/17/Exploring-scalar-types).

Comment: That is a bad reference because it is wrong, one would have hoped books were proofed better. At first glance `float`, `double`, `char` and `NSUInteger` are all wrong, and there is no `short`.

Answer (score 1):

1. char      : A character 1 byte
2. int       :An integer — a whole number  4 bytes
3. float     : Single precision floating point number  4 bytes
4. Double    : Double precision floating point number  8 bytes
5. short     : A short integer 2 bytes
6. long      : A double short  4 bytes
7. long long : A double long   8 bytes
8. BOOL      : Boolean (signed char)   1 byte

For more on sizes check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107544/types-in-objective-c-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Integer types are signed 2's complement or unsigned and the standard C variations are provided (`char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` and `unsigned` variants of these, see [C types on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)), sizes may vary dependent on 32-bit & 64-bit environments - see [64-bit computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing).

`BOOL` is an Objective-C special and is defined as `signed char`, while it can take any value a signed char can the constants `NO` and `YES` are defined for use. The C9X type `_Bool`(aka `bool`) is also provided.

`float` & `double` are IEEE 32-bit & 64-bit floating point - see Wikipedia for ranges.

Standard macro contants are provided for the minimum and maximum of all the types, e.g. `INT_MAX` for `int` - again see [C types on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) for these.