# Objective-C NSNumber numberWithLongLong creates integer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsnumber, long-long

When I attempt to create an NSNumber using the numberWithLongLong with a number greater than -2 and less than 13 it returns a number that is casted as an (int).

I see this if I look at the Xcode debugger after stepping over my line.

`NSNumber* numberA = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:-2]; //Debugger shows as (long)-2

NSNumber* numberB = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:-1]; //Debugger shows as (int)-1

NSNumber* numberC = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:12]; //Debugger shows as (int)12

NSNumber* numberD = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:13]; //Debugger shows as (long)13`

To put my problem in context, I am using a long long value for an epoch date that I will end up serializing using BSON and sending across the wire to a webservice. The webservice requires the date to be a java Long.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ummm… You do know that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`. Both are 32-bit signed integers. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107544/types-in-objective-c-on-iphone

Comment: Additional info you could add to your question: numbers B and C return `"i"` for their `objCType`, whereas A and D return `"q"`. It also happens when you suffix the numeric literals with `LL`, or use `alloc`/`initWithLongLong:`. Did this testing in the debugger on an iPad 3rd gen running iOS 5.1

Comment: What's the problem you are actually having with this? What the debugger shows isn't very relevant compared to what you actually need to do with the `NSNumber` objects.

Comment: @CarlVeazey So, `+numberWithLongLong:` returns an NSNumber object with an `"i"` objCType?

Comment: @JefferyThomas yes, I did some further testing  actually. On iOS 5.1 device and 6.1 sim it returns `"i"`. My Mac running 10.8.3 it returns `"q"`. Also tried `initWithBytes:objCType:` but contrary to convention this returns an NSValue even when called on an NSNumber instance.

Comment: @CarlVeazey yeah, I just read rob's answer. That is crazy. I trust NSNumber much less now.

Comment: Why does it really matter what size of number is stored internally?  I mean, as long as you can say `[number longLongValue]` and get the right value back...why is it a problem that the runtime saves a few bytes?  This seems like encapsulation at work, and i don't see yet why it shouldn't be trusted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have discovered that NSNumber (actually, its CFNumber counterpart) has a cache for integers between -1 and 12 inclusive.  Take a look at the `CFNumberCreate` function in [`CFNumber.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.12/CFNumber.c) to see how it works.

It looks like you can force it not to use the cache by passing your own allocator to [`CFNumberCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/cc8a92/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNumberRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFNumberCreate).  You'll need to look at the [`CFAllocator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/cc8a92/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFAllocatorRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFAllocatorCreate) documentation.

But note that the `CFNumberCreate` manual says this:

> The `theType` parameter is not necessarily preserved when creating a new `CFNumber` object.

So even if you bypass the cache, you might not get back an object whose `objCType` is `q` (which means `long long`).  It looks like the current implementation will return `q` but that could change in a future version.

You are allowed to write your own `NSNumber` subclass if you need to guarantee that `objCType` returns `q`.  Read [“Subclassing Notes” in the *NSNumber Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-DontLinkElementID_1).

Comment: Do you think `long long x = 1; NSValue *number = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&x objCType:"q"];` would work better? Yes, it's a value not a number, but won't the type get preserved?

Comment: If you want to guarantee that you get an `NSNumber` with an `objCType` of `q`, you can write your own subclass of `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your webservice without concern.

`NSNumber` wraps a numeric value (of primitive type) as an object. How `NSNumber` stores that value is not really your concern (but there is a method to find it out), it is an *opaque* type. However `NSNumber` does maintain an internal record of the type used to create it so its `compare:` method can follow C rules for comparison between values of different types precisely.

For *integral types* the *integral value* you get back will be exactly the same, in the mathematical sense, as the one you created the `NSNumber` with. You can create an `NSNumber` with a `short` and read its value back as a `long long`, and the mathematical value will be the same even though the representation is different.

So you can store your integral date value as an `NSNumber` and when you read it back as a `long long` you will get the right value. No need to be concerned how `NSNumber` represents it internally, and indeed that could potentially change in the future.

*(At least one implementation of `NSNumber` can store values as 128-bit integers, which helps ensure correct semantics for signed and unsigned integers. Also I stressed integral types as with the vagaries of real numbers talking about mathematical exactness is somewhat moot.)*

Answer (score 1):

Wait. I think I know what your asking. Try it this way:

```
NSNumber* numberA = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:-2LL];
NSNumber* numberB = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:-1LL];
NSNumber* numberC = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:12LL];
NSNumber* numberD = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:13LL];
```

BTW: it won't matter what the type of the constant is, it will be coerced into a `long long` when passed to `[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:]`

---

**UPDATE**

Based on @robmayoff's answer, I don't think NSNumber is reliable for your. How are you packing your BSON? is there a way to use NSValue instead of NSNumber?

Comment: i don't think this will make any difference... compile should always cast int to long long before pass it as argument anyway

Comment: @xlc Automatic casting done by the compiler is called coercion. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion