# Why the enum size is different. in Swift

Tags: swift

I am making an app that connect between iPhone.
It use enum specify UInt32. but sizeof() is different size.
Why not equal a UInt32?

```
enum Message:UInt32{
    case A = 1
    case B = 2
    case C = 3
}

sizeof(UInt32)    // 4
sizeof(Message)   // 1
```

Comment: both are equal because at any point of time it store only one value only so simple

Comment: Interesting. I would call it a bug, since this is what's least expected.

Answer (score 0):

They must be optimising the storage, the following works:

```
sizeofValue(Message.A.toRaw()) // 4
```

Comment: Changing third member to `case C = 32767` makes no difference to `sizeof(Message)`.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to. My guess is that Message is a pointer into an array of types. In the case of short examples there are less than 256 types in use, therefore Message is 8 bit. The values A, B, and C are not stored in the Message constant they are stored in the Type Message.

Comment: I see what you mean now you elaborate!

Comment: "enum Message:UInt32{...}", this to become UInt32,  not type Message but  values A,B and C ?.

Comment: @kuninory The type of message isn't UInt32 it is Message and despite what the syntax implies (which I find misleading) it is not derived from UInt32 (Message isNotA UInt32). However the enumerations inside Message, A, B, and C, are UInt32s. Therefore Message doesn't have to have a size of 4, but the enumerations A,B, and C, do have to have a size of 4.

Answer (score 0):

When calling an instance of an enum object with no additional method, it returns the type of enum it is (UInt32, in this case).

In reference to this answer, [Types in objective-c on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107544/types-in-objective-c-on-iphone) , an Unsigned Int is 32 **4 bytes**.