# Current time milliseconds returns minus value for 32 bit in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, date, xcode5

I need to get the current time from system in milliseconds. I'm using XCode 5.1.1 and I tried with the following,

`long timePassed_ms = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000);`

This is working fine with `iPad Retina(64-bit)` emulator. But when I'm running this on `iPad(32 bit)` emulator, it returns minus value.

**Output**

`In 32bit iPad : -2147483648`

`In 64bit iPad : 1408416635774(This is the correct time)`

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interval for values of long type is:

–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Try to use long long instead, which uses 8 bytes, and has the interval:

–9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

If you are getting the wrong results using long long, try to use double, but make sure you format the result properly in case you need to place it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

`long` is only `4` bytes on the 32-bit iPad (max value `2147483647`) so it's overflowing. You should be using `long long` or `double` instead (`double` is actually what `timeIntervalSince1970` returns so it's probably the best choice):

```
double timePassed_ms = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000);
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107544/types-in-objective-c-on-iphone) has a good list of the available types and their sizes.